# Tango Predefined Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm somewhat familiar with tango and unity. I have worked through the examples and can get them to work correctly. I have seen some people doing an AR type example where they have their custom objects in an area to interact with or another example would be directions where you follow a line to a destination.

The one thing I cannot figure out is how to precisely place a 3d object into a scene. How are people getting that data to place it within unity in the correct location? I ha e an area set up and the AR demo seems promising but I'm not placing objects with the click of a finger. What I am looking to do is when they walk by my 3d object will already be there and they can interact with it. Any ideas? I feel like I've been searching everywhere with little luck to an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, I have a specific space the user will always be in - so I place things in the (single room) scene when I compile.

- I Create an ADF using the provided apps, and then my app has a mode where it does the 3D Reconstruction and saves off the mesh.
- I then load the Mesh into my Unity Scene (I have to rotate it by 180° in the Y axis because of how I am saving the .obj files)
- You now have a guide letting you place objects exactly where you want them, and a nice environment to build up your scene.
- I disable the mesh before I build.  When tango localises, your unity stuff matches up with the tango world space.

If you want to place objects programatically, you can place them in scripts using [Instantiate](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning/Scripts/AreaLearningInGameController.cs#L653)
I also sometimes have my app place markers with a touch, like in the examples, and record the positions to a file, which I then use to place objects specifically... But having a good mesh loaded into your scene is really the nicest way i've found.

Comment: I will give that a try. Did you create the mesh and adf at the same time or can you scan and create the adf then go back and scan to create the mesh? Or does your app do both at the same time? I thought that scanning the mesh was the way to go so i tried it. I also had to rotate 180 degrees since is twas backwards but never did relocalizing. That is probably my issue.

I also tried grabbing the position of the AR example pins but it was never accurate depending on where you are when you place it. it was always 0.1 or 0.2 range which didn't help for placing in world positions.

Comment: I scanned an ADF first using the example app which works fine.  Then build my mesh only after relocalising correctly to that ADF, within my app..  It seems to work best in this way for me.

Some apps would obviously need to do everything at once if they do not know their space beforehand.  You can do a nice long scan once, and then work from that lengthy scan.

I've found the accuracy is really good so far, drift sometimes takes a while to relocalise out of, but overall things stay put well.

Comment: So when you do the mesh scan you are using the ADF file. Are you checking "Use Area Description Pose" under Enable 3D Reconstruction?

Comment: Yes i have to type more characters to comment Yep

Comment: I think where I'm getting caught up is your last bullet point. Are you just setting the gameObject active in 'OnTangoPoseAvailable'? I feel like I keep getting caught in a loop trying to figure it out. Can you share an example of how you're having it turn active once it's localized and having it match up to the tango world space?

Comment: I finally solved this. I was way over thinking it. I put this code on my script to start the Tango Application Permissions. now if Only I knew how to add code to the comments without going over my limit. I basically used that function 'OnTangoPoseAvailable' to enable the 3d objects.

Comment: Glad it's sorted (:
You can also listen to OnTangoPoseAvailable(TangoPoseData pose), and when it gets called first time you do your stuff that needs localisation like drawing more objects into the scene.  This gives you useful handles on where you localised to, where you were when tango initialised, etc...   https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/interface/i-tango-pose
Have fun!